# I didn't receive an email telling me that my bounty is about to expire

Tags: support, bounty

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452209/how-to-use-supervisorctl-on-ubuntu), I did not receive an email telling that my bounty is about to expire in 24h, I use gmail, nothing in spam.

I have CS finals at university so I don't have time to keep checking this site, I don't have time to try solutions, the guy was lucky that I remembered to check that post, I rewarded him the bounty with 5 minutes left, without trying anything. He was lucky because I was on my PC, I couldn't have rewarded him anything on mobile app.

[Also this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134874/how-to-auto-scan-any-plugged-in-usb-storage-device-with-clamav), I wasn't alerted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bounties have an extra grace period past the original 7 days.

You get email notifications when the 7 days end and you enter the grace period.

Comment: past the original 7 days? I thought it was the last day of the 7 days, btw I just received the email even though I rewarded the bounty

Comment: Think beyond your limits, mortal. And you shall transcend...

Comment: Roger that, Zeus

Comment: I am Madara Uchiha, Zeus is my b***h.